# How to create a responsive linear-gradient while keeping the angle unchanged?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Hello Everyone here i wanted to change, We need to update the strikethrough to be the same diagonal - 45 degrees centered. Please find the code at below...

```css
.Product__widths__button {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.Product__widths__button.disabled {
    color: #D1D1D1;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, #fff 38px, #D1D1D1, #fff 40px);
    border-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

```html
<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)</a>
```

Here wanted to display like below image

[image]

Please let me if anything more needs from my side. Thanks!!!

Comment: the height will be fixed?

Comment: yes.. here we can't able to change height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the height is fixed you can set the background size to be a square with dimension equal to height (`42px` in your case) and center it like below:

```css
.Product__widths__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.Product__widths__button.disabled {
  color: #D1D1D1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, 
      /*the center is 42px*cos(45deg) = 29.7px, we remove/add pixel around*/
      transparent 28px,#D1D1D1,transparent 31px) 
      center/42px 100% /*background-position/background-size  (100% is your height)*/
      no-repeat;
  border-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

```html
<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)</a>
```

Another idea is to make the gradient a big square in case you don't know the exact height and it will work with dynamic height.

```css
.Product__widths__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.Product__widths__button.disabled {
  color: #D1D1D1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, 
      /* the center is 500px*cos(45deg) = 353.5px*/
      transparent 351px,#D1D1D1,transparent 355px) 
      center/500px 500px /*background-position/background-size */
      no-repeat;
  border-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

```html
<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)</a>

<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)<br>another line</a>
```

Another way without `background-size` and `background-position` is to simply set the degree to be `-45deg` and you need to find the center using `calc()` combined with `50%`

```css
.Product__widths__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.Product__widths__button.disabled {
  color: #D1D1D1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent calc(50% - 2px),#D1D1D1,transparent calc(50% + 2px));
  border-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

```html
<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)</a>

<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)<br>another line</a>
```

---

You can also try this using a skewed element as background where you will have better support in case you cannot use `calc()`

```css
.Product__widths__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.Product__widths__button.disabled {
  color: #D1D1D1;
  border-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.Product__widths__button.disabled::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:calc(50% - 2px); /*we remove half the border-width to have a perfect centring*/
  border-right:4px solid #D1D1D1;
  transform:skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)</a>

<a id="width_1_1" class="Product__widths__button disabled"><span>W</span> (Wide)<br>another line</a>
```