# Linear-gradient or calc() not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, linear-gradients, css-calc

I have a problem regarding the linear-gradient, IE11 and maybe calc() function.

This code snippet acts different on Chrome and IE11.

`background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #ccc, transparent calc(50% + 1px));`

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBAhW.png)
[IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezkQ.png)

I want it to look like Chrome version.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. IE11 doesn't like the calc() function. I used instead of `calc(50% - 1px)` and `calc(50% + 1px)` absolute values that were half of the div size +-1.

Comment: I suggest that if the solution works for you, you could mark is as answer so that it will be helpful for someone meets with the similar issue.

Comment: Yup, I did that as I just saw your comment... damn I need to start using stackoverflow on a daily basics. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea where you don't need to know the size of the div but you won't have transparency:

```css
.box {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top   right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) top    -1px right -1px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) bottom -1px left  -1px,
    #ccc;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

/* irrelevant styles */
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:200px">
</div>
<div class="box" style="height:200px">
</div>
```

Similar question with other ideas: [linear-gradient border modify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54942581/8620333)